# I am not able to view the index page when mapping to a different port in docker container

Tags: image, docker, containers, port

`docker ps` output :

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND              CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                   NAMES
b9de23ba7714        httpd:latest        "httpd-foreground"   9 seconds ago       Up 7 seconds        0.0.0.0:32768->80/tcp   learn_httpd_2
37ce84785cbd        httpd:latest        "httpd-foreground"   28 minutes ago      Up 28 minutes       0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp      learn_httpd
```

The learn_httpd is accessible from windows browser with the public_ip:80 but learn_httpd_2 is not accessible public_ip:32768. Do i need to change any setting in windows or am i missing something. My docker is running on a unix box and i am using the public ip of my unix machine

Answer (score 0):

You maybe need do open the port 32768 in your virtual machine so that windows can access it.